# How do I handle a user pressing the cancel button in a QInputDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

This is my first week doing Qt so forgive me if I don't understand the basics that well. In the commented part of the code below I'd like to write code that handles the cancel button on `QInputDialog`.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {              
  QApplication app(argc, argv);                  
  QTextStream cout(stdout);                       
  int answer;

  do {  
    int celciusArg = 0;
    int farenheit;
    celciusArg = QInputDialog::getInt(0, "Celcius Calculator",
        "Convert this number to Farenheit:", 1);

    // I'd like to say here:
    // if (user clicked cancel)
    //      then (close the widget)

    cout << "User entered: " << celciusArg
         << endl;
    farenheit = celciusArg * 1.8 + 32;

    QString response = QString("%1 degrees celcius is %2 degrees farenheit .\n%3")
        .arg(celciusArg).arg(farenheit)        /* Each %n is replaced with an arg() value. */
        .arg("Convert another temperature?");  /* Long statements can continue on multiple lines, as long as they are broken on token boundaries. */
    answer = QMessageBox::question(0, "Play again?", response,
        QMessageBox::Yes| QMessageBox::No);    /* Bitwise or of two values. */
  } while (answer == QMessageBox::Yes);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Didn't test it but perhaps connect the ```rejected``` signal from the dialog to the handler function?

Comment: While this question is fairly basic, it does include the complete source code - so kudos to the asker for that. The downvotes are fairly unwarranted IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Reading documentation helps a lot:

> If ok is nonnull *ok will be set to true if the user pressed OK and to false if the user pressed Cancel. The dialog's parent is parent. The dialog will be modal and uses the widget flags.

Full prototype is:

```
int QInputDialog::getInt(QWidget * parent, const QString & title, const QString & label, int value = 0, int min = -2147483647, int max = 2147483647, int step = 1, bool * ok = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0)
```

So here you need only to use `bool * ok`:

```
bool isOkPressed{};
int celciusArg = 0;
int farenheit;
celciusArg = QInputDialog::getInt(0, "Celcius Calculator",
    "Convert this number to Farenheit:", 1, -2147483647, 2147483647, 1, &isOkPressed);

if (isOkPressed) {
    // here you go
}
```

[QInputDialog::getInt() documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html#getInt)

Answer (score 3):

Change to

```
bool ok;
celciusArg = QInputDialog::getInt(0, "Celcius Calculator",
    "Convert this number to Farenheit:", 0, 0, 100, 1, &ok);

if (ok)
    //pressed ok
else
    //pressed cancel
```

the first zero is the default value, the second is the minimum value, 100 should be the maximum value and 1 is the increment/decrement, if you want to get temperature from -100 C to 200 C starting from 30 C you must use

```
celciusArg = QInputDialog::getInt(0, "Celcius Calculator",
    "Convert this number to Farenheit:", 30, -100, 200, 1, &ok);
```

Comment: That's interesting. Another question I have is when we have 'QInputDialog::getInt()' why is there a scope resolution operator? The only time I have ever seen it is when you define member functions for a class.

Comment: Because `getInt` is a static member of `QInputDialog` class